# If k-th moment is 0 then f is 0

Tags: functional-analysis

So suppose we have $f \in C[0,1] $. And then we have $\int_{0}^{1} x^k f(x) \ dx=0 $ for all $k\geq 0$, how do I show that $f\equiv 0 $?

I know that the polynomials are dense in the space of continuous functions on $[0,1]$ . How can I use this?

Comment: Prove that $\int_0^1|f(x)|^2\,dx = 0$ and conclude that this implies $f\equiv 0$. The idea is to approximate $f$ with a polynomial $p$ and conclude that $\int_0^1|f(x)|^2\,dx \approx \int_0^1 f(x)p(x)\,dx = 0$ by linearity of the integral. You're left with carrying out the details.

Comment: So I did $f^2(x)-f(x)p(x)\leq |f^2(x)-f(x)p(x)|\leq ||f^2-fp||_{\infty } \leq ||f||_{\infty }||f-p||_{\infty } < \epsilon .$ So $\int_{0}^{1} (f^2(x)-f(x)p(x)) \ dx < \epsilon $. Does this all hold?

Comment: Yes, almost. You have $\|f\|_\infty\|f-p\|_\infty < \|f\|_\infty\epsilon$. So, $\int_0^1 f^2(x)\,dx < \|f\|_\infty\epsilon + \int_0^1f(x)p(x)\,dx = \|f\|_\infty\epsilon$ for each $\epsilon > 0$. That is, $\int_0^1f^2(x)\,dx = 0$.

Comment: Yes and by $f^2 \geq 0 $ and being continuous $f^2$ and so $f$ is identically 0.